# PHP Foreach with mysql_fetch_array server status

Tags: php

Im trying to create a cronjob script, which checks the status of a few servers.
Somehow it only uses the first ip in my table.

```
$aQ = db::aQuery("SELECT hostIp FROM `gh_server_hosts`");
$a = mysql_fetch_array($aQ);
foreach ($a as $value) {

        $timeout = "10";
        $ssh= @fsockopen("$value","22",$timeout);

         if($ssh) {
            $status = 1;
         }
         else {
            $status = 0;
         }

         $time = time();
        if(db::aQuery("UPDATE `gh_server_hosts` SET hostLastScanned='".$time."', hostLastStatus='".$status."' WHERE hostIp = '".$value."'")) {
                echo "scanned";
            } else {
                echo "error";
            }
}
```

Comment: Because `mysql_fetch_array` fetches one record.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `mysql_fetch_array` in loop to get all records like this:

```
$aQ = db::aQuery("SELECT hostIp FROM `gh_server_hosts`");

while ($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($aQ)) {
    $timeout = "10";
    $ssh= @fsockopen($value['hostIp'],"22",$timeout);

    // Rest of your code
}
```

I have used `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` to limit the output array. Also, as mentioned by others `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so kindly update your code before running this code on PHP 5.5+...

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` will work instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` but do note about the [deprecation warning with mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).  (Aside from the security concerns, your code will fail if PHP is upgraded to 7.0).